# same question different way

Tags: syntactic-analysis

During college, I worked the summers landscaping, which cultivated a fascination with wild plants and folk medicine.

or this:

During college, I worked the summers as a landscaper, cultivating a fascination in wild plants and folk medicine.

or this:

During college, I worked the summers landscaping, cultivating a fascination with wild plants and folk medicine.

Comment: Unless you're specifically intending to be "quirky", that metaphorical ***cultivated*** is a definite howler. Whatever - I think this is Off Topic writing advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice


Comment: The best thing to do is to edit your previous question. There isn't actually a question here, and if there were it would be asking for writing advice.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking which one sounds more formal?  Whether one of them is less grammatically correct than the other?  Which to use in formal speech?  Whethere there is any difference between the three? You've given us three different sentences done in different ways, but youd didn't present a question.

Comment: That’s two [correction: ***THREE***] duplicate questions that are not questions at all. Please actually take the time to read the description of how to ask questions before randomly bombarding the site with un-thought-through postings.

Comment: _I worked summers as a landscaper during college, which cultivated a fascination with wild plants and folk medicine._ That's probably how I'd word it. But this really isn't the right place to ask questions like the one you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to EL&U.  I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you're not really asking for writing advice but are simply questioning, or are curious about, the differences between the various wordings of sentences that mean essentially the same thing.

They're all good as far as they go.  For a chatty, somewhat informal way of expressing yourself, one is probably as good as the other.

To expand your horizons, you need not stick with your three versions, but you could also recast the sentences and keep the same meaning, with more style and better grammar.  For example, you could draw your readers' attention to your pun by adding a few words; you could add parallel verb structure; you could avoid the troublesome (to me) "summers landscaping"; and you could keep "summers as a landscaper," or some variant of it, and then create a compound sentence, if you wish.  Put them all together and you get the following:

> "During my summer breaks in college I worked as a landscaper, and I cultivated, so to speak, a fascination with wild plants and folk medicine."

Or,

> "During my summer breaks in college I worked as a landscaper and cultivated, as it were, my fascination with wild plants and folk medicine."

Or, keeping the "worked/cultivating":

> "While in college, during my summer breaks I worked as a landscaper, cultivating, so to speak, a fascination with wild plants and folk medicine."

Or,

> "By working as a landscaper during my summers away from college, I cultivated (pun intended) my fascination with wild plants and folk medicine."

Or,

> "By working as a landscaper during my summers away from college, I cultivated, not so coincidentally, a fascination for wild plants and folk medicine."

Or,

> "By working as a landscaper . . . I cultivated, coincidentally, a fascination . . .."

I could go on, but won't. By the way, using either *a* or *my* before *fascination* is fine.  *A* implies you starting developing your fascination by working as a landscaper, whereas *my* implies you already had a fascination but it developed further as you worked as a landscaper.